# Assign list view id error - Android Studio

Tags: java, android, listview, android-studio

I'm new to Android development. I'm using Android studio. I created a listview in xml and when I'm trying to call it in MainActivity(Java file). It gives an error near R.layout.listView .

My code as follows.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
ListView l;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        l=(ListView)findViewById(R.layout.listView);

    }


}
```

Comment: Show us your xml file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Wrong** Tag

```
l=(ListView)findViewById(R.layout.listView);
```

Please set `id` instead of `layout`

Finally

```
     public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    ListView l;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        l=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);

    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
l=(ListView)findViewById(R.layout.listView);
```

To

```
l=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
```

Your code will be like this:

```
   public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    ListView l;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            l=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView); 
        }
    }
```

Comment: @coderaizer you should accept the answer by clicking correct tick.

Answer (score 0):

please check the same id that you have added to your xml file, I mean to say that in your xml file has the same id name **listView** that you have added to your java class.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private ListView l;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            l = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);

        }
    }
```

Comment: @coderaizer: If this answer really helpful to you, you can upvote it, anyways your wlcm :)